# Updating the user logged in to the Python application online or offline

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my python application, when the user logs in, the status in the Mysql database is updated as online, when the python application is closed, the status is updated as offline but the internet connection is lost etc. In some cases, atexit does not work and does not update offline. What should I do? What should I do?

```
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="********",
  user="********",
  password="********",
  database="********"
)


def set_user_online():
  if db_connection.is_connected():
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(
      f"UPDATE bot_accounts SET status = 'online' WHERE serial_key = '{data}' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;")  

    db_connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("user status online")


def set_user_offline():
  if db_connection.is_connected():
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(
      f"UPDATE bot_accounts SET status = 'offline' WHERE serial_key = '{data}' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;")  

    db_connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("user status offline")


set_user_online()
atexit.register(set_user_offline)
```

I try atexit but it doesn't work in all cases.

For example, it does not work when the internet is gone or the computer is turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are facing:

- The connection is interrupted,
- The user does not log off properly,
- The PC shuts down, etc.

These problems are ***so*** common that it must be said quite clearly:
***never*** should a program rely on logging off from `online` status on the client side to work correctly.

***Never ever!***

A lot of people are not even willing to do a proper logout.

So what the other answer said:

Use the last checking time the user was seen, and use a timeout to decide when he has to be considered offline.
This is ***not*** just an "option". This is a must-have.
I would consider it a bug (and a serious one) in the implementation if that was missing.

You ***always*** will have users not having their status updated correctly. Never trust that things on the client side work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One option is instead of is online change it to last checking time and change your logic to decide if you consider them to be online or offline based on time delta.